# Magento, Static Block won't render?

Tags: magento, templates, block, php

this is my local.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="banner" as="banner" translate="label">
                <label>Banner Area</label>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="bannerblock">
            <block type="core/template" name="bannerblock" template="banner.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

this is my 1column.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('banner') ?>
```

I am not sure why it is not rendered. I think it might have to do with the **placement of banner.phtml**

should I put in 
app/design/frontend/x/x/template/

or inside

 
app/design/frontend/x/x/template/page/html/

how do magenta find out?

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing "bannerblock" block from inside of "bannerblock". Try moving the "bannerblock" block delaration into the "root" reference node:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="banner" as="banner" translate="label">
                <label>Banner Area</label>
            </block>
            <block type="core/template" name="bannerblock" template="banner.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```